# SSIS/SSAS How can I show Month.Year as time dimension?

Tags: sql, date, casting, ssis, ssas

I am building a database for some data to build a cube (SSAS) after. Until now everything is fine and works but I want to modify my time dimension. Since now I have a table with year, month and day and use it as dimension. But for my use it would be nice if the hierarchy is not just like (2016-->5-->20); instead I want to show month.year at the month level (in this example: 05.2016). I had no problems separating the date but I can`t find a solution to show this part or to combine the two columns in SSIS. Is there any possibility to do so or can I create this in SSAS while setting up the cube?

What I´ve found out is that with the cast and datepart command I can show the things I want in the SQL Server Manager but I am a newbie in MS SQL and don`t know how to save the calculations in a new column.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You said that you `had no problems separating the date`...then you can use that column directly as an attribute in SSAS

Comment: Yes that`s right, I am using the columns year, month, day via ID to my fact table in the cube but I don`t get it how to combine year and month so that my hierarchy looks like this: year (2015), month (05.2015), day (20.05.2015). You know what I mean? It`s just a luxury problem because I need to work with the cube later in excel and that would make it easier in this step.

Answer (score 1):

Add a MonthYear column to your dimension table and populate it with a derived column transformation in SSIS that concatenates the month and year columns.